# Crontab script does not run properly

Tags: shell, cron-task

I have a script that goes into a directory, checks if a website is available and if it is, starts a cypress script and sends a notificaton.

```
5 * * * 1,3,5 cd /home/username/test/ && ping -c 1 example.com &> /dev/null && (notify-send "Updating Data" && npx cypress run) || notify-send "Data update failed"
```

The logs just say:

```
pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user username(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
(username) CMD (cd /home/username/test/ && ping -c 1 example.com &> /dev/null && (notify-send "Updating Data" && npx cypress run) || notify-send "Data update failed")
pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user username
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Check your mail. Cron sends any output to the user's inbox. Wild guess: the default PATH inherited from cron does not include the directories for ping or notify-send or npx.

Comment: @Jens how do i check the mail? The commands work now but notify-send commands work now, but somehow "/usr/bin/npx cypress run" does not want to work/ gets skipped. Do you know how i can run  "/usr/bin/npx cypress run"? In the commadline it seems to work, but in cron it doesnt.

Comment: Cronjobs do not source any shell startup files. If your script needs any environment variables, it might not find them. I suggest you 1) Put your crontab line in a script named `foo.sh`. 2) Test it with a reduced environent by running `env -i ./foo.sh`. Fix all problems, e.g. set PATH in `foo.sh` and anything else that may be missing.

Comment: Check your mail with a mail client. Maybe `mailx` works.